# ASP.NET Core MVC <form method="post"> gives an empty constructor to the ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this `Index.cshtml`:

```cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@model Xy;
@*...*@
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="x" value="@Model.x" />
        <input type="number" name="y" step="0.01"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn"/>
    </form>
```

And two methods that return an `IActionResult` in `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    float x = (float)Round(new Random().NextDouble()*24+1,2);
    return View(new Xy(x));
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Xy Answer)
{
    //...
}
```

And, accordingly, the class `Xy`:

```
public class Xy
{
    public float x;
    public float? y;

    public Xy()
    {
        x = float.NaN;
        y = null;
    }

    public Xy(float X, float? Y = null)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
}
```

Why when I click the button, the `post` gives an empty `Xy()` to `Index(X y Answer)`? That is, with `x` = `NaN` instead of `@Model.x` and `y` = `null` ignoring the `<input type="number" name="y" step="0.01"/>` field?

Besides of minimizing the code (here I have given the minimized code), I also tried to replace "name" with "asp-for" and "asp-form" – it did not help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may need to change your fields to properties.

Comment: Do you mean, replace `name="y"` by `name="Y"` and so on? That didn't works

Comment: No, I mean make them public [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of public Fields.

Comment: O, I see, I need to add `{ get; set; }` to x,y declarations in class. Wasn't know that it makes so much difference. Now it's works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a misunderstanding of the difference between fields and properties. In order for everything to work, it is the properties that need to be declared in the class, not the fields – that is, instead of

```cs
public float x;
public float? y;
```

should be

```cs
public float x { get; set; }
public float? y { get; set; }
```